# Tokenizing string for completion suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

want to build the auto complete functionality of an e-commerce website, using Completion Suggester.

This is my Index:

```
PUT myIndex
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion"
                },
                "title" : {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }, 
                "category" : { 
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "description" : { 
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when uploading the advertisement I want the title field to be used for auto complete, so this is how I upload a document:

```
POST dummy/_doc
{
  "title": "Blue asics running shoes",
  "category": "sports",
  "description": "Nice blue running shoes, size 44 eu",
  "suggest": {
    "input": "Blue Asics running shoes" // <-- use title
  }
}
```

Problem is, this way, elastic search only matches the string from beginning... i.e. "Blu" will find result but "Asic" or "Run" or "Sho" won't return anything...

So what I need to do is to tokenize my input like this:

```
POST dummy/_doc
{
  "title": "Blue asics running shoes",
  "category": "sports",
  "description": "Nice blue running shoes, size 44 eu",
  "suggest": {
    "input": ["Blue", "Asics", "running", "shoes"] // <-- tokenized title
  }
}
```

This would work fine... But how am I supposed to tokenize my field? I know I can split the string in c#, but is there anyway that I can do this in Elasticsearch/Nest?

Comment: As I see «type = "standard"» is what are you looking for

Comment: But how to tell ES to use the standard analyzer in the mapping? I would prefer English Language Analyzer...

Comment: ES uses `Standard Analyzer` by default. Point is you are using wrong datatype. Change `keyword` to `text`. `'keyword` doesn't go through analysis process and breaks the words into token. You need to use `text`

Comment: Have a look on the ngram tokenizer as you need to generate partial tokens. You should also consider using a separate field on which you'll search the autocomplete queries. In this way you can define different processing for the title and autocomplete field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) is designed for fast search-as-you-type **prefix** queries, using a `simple` analyzer, and not the `standard` analyzer which is default for `text` datatypes.

If you need partial prefix matching on *any* tokens in the title and not just from the beginning of the title, you may want to consider taking one of these approaches:

1. use [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) with an analyzer that will tokenize the title into tokens/terms from which you would want to partial prefix match, and index this collection as the `input` to the `completion` field. The Standard analyzer may be a good one to start with.

   Bear in mind that the data structure for completion suggester is held in memory whilst in use, so high terms cardinality across documents will increase the memory demands of this data structure. Also consider that "scoring" of matching terms is simple in that it is controlled by the weight applied to each input.

or

2. Don't use the Completion Suggester here and instead set up the `title` field as a `text` datatype with [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) that include the different ways that `title` should be analyzed (or not analyzed, with a `keyword` sub field for example).

   Spend some time with the Analyze API to build an analyzer that will allow for partial prefix of terms anywhere in the title. As a start, something like the Standard tokenizer, Lowercase token filter, Edgengram token filter and possibly Stop token filter would get you running. Also note that you would want a [Search analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) that does something similar to the Index analyzer *except* Edgengram token filter, as tokens in the search input would not need to be ngrammed.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am not sure I understand what you mean by Standard  Tokenizer? [I have posted my code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097275/tokening-string-for-completion-suggester/53111253#53111253), I am using edge_ngram tokenizer... but did you say I should use Standard Tokenizer?

Comment: The Standard Analyzer uses the Standard Tokenizer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html. In your custom analyzer, you're using EdgeNGram _tokenizer_, but you may want to use Standard Tokenizer and perform edge ngramming with the EdgeNGram token filter. Without knowledge of your domain, it's tricky to make specific recommendations, but a good place to start is with the Standard Tokenizer in a custom analyzer, until you find that it doesn't tokenize how you'd like, then look at something else :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ, I updated my answer below in case it would be useful for other people. I added  "symbol" & "punctuation" to my ngrams, to catch things like "C#". I am not sure if I can improve this solution to exclude spelling mistakes?

Comment: For indexing, it can be very much a case of Garbage In, Garbage Out i.e. if you can sanitize and improve the index input _before_ indexing, that is nearly always better than trying to fix with analysis. For querying, you can add fuzziness to a full-text query to cater for misspelling. Another approach is to use phonetic token filters to index phonetic representations to find matches on similar sounding terms

Answer (score 1):

Based on Russ Cam's answer above (option 2), [this Elasticsearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) and also [this document](https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams), I ended up with the following solution:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "edge_ngram_token_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10
        },
        "additional_stop_words": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  ["your"]
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "C# => csharp",
            "c# => csharp"
          ]
        }
       },
       "analyzer": {
        "result_suggester_analyzer": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter":  [ "html_strip", "my_char_filter" ],
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "stop",
            "additional_stop_words",
            "english_stemmer",
            "edge_ngram_token_filter",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query to test this solution:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "result_suggester_analyzer",
  "text": "C# &amp; SQL are great languages. K2 is the mountaineer's mountain. Your house-décor is à la Mode"
}
```

I would get these tokens (NGrams):

```
cs, csh, csha, cshar, csharp, sq, sql, gr, gre, grea, great, la, lan, lang,
langu, langua, languag, k2, mo, mou, moun, mount, mounta, mountai, mountain, 
ho, hou, hous, hous, de, dec, deco, decor, mod, mode
```

Things to note here:

1. I am using `stop` filter, which is the default English language
   filter and is blocking `are, is, the` - but not `your`.
2. I have defined the `additional_stop_words`, which stops `your`
3. I am using built in `english` & `possessive_english` stemmers, which would tokenize the words stems: that's why we have *languag* token but not language or languages... also note that we have *mountain* but not *mountaineering*.
4. I have defined `mapped_words_char_filter` which convert C# to csharp, without this c# would not be a valid token... (this setting would not tokenize F#)
5. I am using built in `html_strip`, `char_filter` which converts `&amp;` to &, and it is ignored since our min_gram = 2
6. We are using built it `asciifolding` token filter and that's why *décor* is tokenized as *decor*.

---

This is the NEST code for the above:

```
var createIndexResponse = ElasticClient.CreateIndex(IndexName, c => c
    .Settings(st => st
        .Analysis(an => an
            .Analyzers(anz => anz
                .Custom("result_suggester_analyzer", cc => cc
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .CharFilters("html_strip", "mapped_words_char_filter")
                    .Filters(new string[] { "english_possessive_stemmer", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "stop", "english_stemmer", "edge_ngram_token_filter", "unique" })
                )
            )
            .CharFilters(cf => cf
                .Mapping("mapped_words_char_filter", md => md
                    .Mappings(
                        "C# => csharp",
                        "c# => csharp"
                    )
                )
            )
            .TokenFilters(tfd => tfd
                .EdgeNGram("edge_ngram_token_filter", engd => engd
                    .MinGram(2)
                    .MaxGram(10)
                )
                .Stop("additional_stop_word", sfd => sfd.StopWords(new string[] { "your" }))
                .Stemmer("english_stemmer", esd => esd.Language("english"))
                .Stemmer("english_possessive_stemmer", epsd => epsd.Language("possessive_english"))
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m.Map<AdDocument>(d => d.AutoMap())));
```