# Ignoring Edge NGrams in some queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have followed [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) to create an auto-completion search... what I am doing is to use [Edge NGram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer, to tokenize one of my fields (title). I used these Edge NGrams for my auto-completion search [this is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097275/tokening-string-for-completion-suggester/53111253#53111253).

The auto-complete works fine... but it has broken my search functionality... because now when I use my main search (not the auto-complete) it still searches the NGrams... for example, if I search for "Ski", the result would contain both Ski and Skirt. For my main search, I don't want Skirt to be a match when searching Ski.

Is it possible to configure Elasticsearch to ignore Edge NGrams in some queries and use them in other queries?

Comment: is your main search happens when user press enter on search bar ?

Comment: Yes, I have a search textbox where I don't want the Edge NGrams. I have another auto-complete textbox on a different page where I want to use the Egde NGrams.

Comment: ohh great, then its a same use case, pl refer my answer below and lert me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement but in my application auto-complete is different than the main search. auto-completion happens as user is typing and main search happens when user press enter.

Auto-complete and main search results are different in our application as its a requirement in your case. Also it's a general practice.

**How I solved this use case :-**

1. For autocomplete instead of index time, we used the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/prefix-query.html there are pros and cons b/w doing this index time and query time.
2. For main search it doesn't use the prefix search, hence partial search doesn't happen.

**Example**
1. If title field contains `foo`, `bar`, `hello`, `world` than prefix search will bring the result for `f`, `fo` but not for `oo`. If you want `oo` to be searchable then you need to use 2 different fields for autocomplete and main search that's the only solution.
Otherwise just change your query type to prefix in case of autocomplete and in this case, your index size will also be very less.
We did some testing on if we use edge-N gram token then it was increasing our index size to be doubled, which was not a choice for us as we have very large indexes.

**Edit**
If you want to have a substring search, for term `runni` you want title `New Balance Running Shoes` should come in search result then I would advise you to create 2 fields like title_autocomplete which uses edge n-gram analyzer and used for autocomplete query and title which uses some other analyzer like standard or something else which solves your main search use case.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your answer... in my case, auto-complete field, is the title of an Ad on an e-commerce website. So Imagine the title is: "New Balance Running Shoes". Would a prefix query still work if user types: "Runni" or does it have to start from beginning of the term?

Comment: @Hooman , it won't work for `Runni` . as you expected it has to start from the beginning. In this case, its a substring search and then you have to create edge n gram tokens which you already created, but just create 2 fields like title_autocomplete which uses edge n gram analyzer and used for autocomplete query and title which uses some other analyzer like standard or something else which solves your main search use case.

Comment: Thanks Amit, sounds like using a second field is my best option.