# Elasticsearch partial matching order

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to return the sku's in order of what the field begins with, without adding any additional data to the index?

Example search query: EXP-0931

This is returning: NI-EXP-0931 as the first result, in second comes EXP-0931/03/P

We want products with EXP* to come first, I've tried turning off fuzzyiness, limiting to only the sku field etc had a read through the docs can't get constant query to work either.

The mapping for my sku field:

```
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
```

Example POST request

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"sku": "EXP"}
    }
}
```

Example Result

```
{
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.5989681,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "magento2_en_catalog_product_20190202_000937",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "398925",
                "_score": 0.5989681,
                "_source": {
                    "sku": "NI-EXP-0931"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "magento2_en_catalog_product_20190202_000937",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "398923",
                "_score": 0.55341274,
                "_source": {
                    "sku": " EXP-0931/03/P"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using the Shingle mapping

```
 "sku": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "untouched": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "copy_to": [
                                    "search",
                                    "spelling"
                                ],
                                "analyzer": "shingle"
                            },
```

Comment: Is re-indexing an option - if you hit on the right solution? Or does this have to be a query-only solution?

Comment: re-indexing would be fine

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure but I wondered if this would help: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html If you could get the regex right it would see the "NI-" bit as a token separator which would index on the "EXP*" bit at the end. I guess you'd need a nested property using that analyzer and then you could sort on that. I must stress I haven't tried it but could be worth a shot.

Comment: Are you able to include your index definition code? The bit of code which contains: <analyzer name="shingle" tokenizer="whitespace" language="default">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to search for something which begins with: *EXP*

But you are getting results like: NI-EXP-0931 which is not desired.

I recommend reading about [tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) to see how you want to tokenize your terms... for example, if you use [Whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) then your search term, `NIC-EXP-0931` would remain one word, but if you use [Standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) you would get 3 tokens (NIC, EXP, 0931) for the same term.

If you use White space tokenizer, then NIC-EXP-0931 should not be returned when you search for EXP-0931

---

If you want to be able to do a completion search (words beginning with: *EX*) then I suggest reading about token filters: [N-Gram and Edge N-Gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html#_partial_word_tokenizers) token filters. They would tell Elasticsearch how to do the completion search for you...

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097275/tokenizing-string-for-completion-suggester) for some example and references for building a completion suggester.

Comment: Thanks, the library I use has an analyzer setup for this "shingle" i've set the field to use that, which has  <analyzer name="shingle" tokenizer="whitespace" language="default"> and I can see in my mappings it's using shingle as the analyzer. However query match still bringing back the NI- sku

Comment: You need to show us more of your code... I am not clear how you are doing the completion search? For example can user type "ex" and expect some result?

Comment: The library I'm using doesn't allow configuring NGram OTB, however this isn't for autocomplete it's just a standard match request using the full search term the user provided. I've added an example POST

Comment: @JoelDavey: If you are typing "EXP" and getting "EXP-0931/03/P" as a result, then you must have used a completion suggester that tokenize your term into nGrams...